# How to clear the cache for JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm reading a JSON file with jQuery. If I update the file that `.get()` reads it still gets the old values when I read the newer file. Since I write and read the file every second, how can I solve this problem? Manually clearing the cache won't be a option.

```
function readEye() {

    $.getJSON('output.json', function(data){

        console.log(data);

    });

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) settings

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache:false
});
```

after that you can use your code like

```
function readEye() {
  $.getJSON('output.json', function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```