# When I update MySQL row when i request same row by json i recieve old value

Tags: php, mysql, jsonp

when I update MySQL row when i request same row  by json i receive old value Although the 
the value on server correct in phpMyAdmin . and after calling 2 or three time receive the correct value .

```
 $id=$_POST['id']; 
 $type=$_POST['type'];
 $study=$_POST['study']; 
 $text=$_POST['text'];
 $date=$_POST['date'];
 $picture=$_POST['picture'];
 $notes=$_POST['notes'];

 $text= addslashes($text);
 $text=htmlspecialchars($text);

 $notes= addslashes($notes);
 $notes= htmlspecialchars($notes);

 $continued = mysql_connect(localhost,somebodyuser,password);

 if($continued){
echo("");
}else{
echo("Connection is fail");
 }
mysql_select_db("u599749231_rose")or die("cannot select DB");
 mysql_query("set character_set_server='utf8'");
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'"); 

 $update=mysql_query("UPDATE achive SET type= '$type', study = '$study', text= '$text',        
 date = '$date' , picture ='$picture' , notes = '$notes'  WHERE id='$id'");


  if($update)  
    {  
   echo'1';

   }  
   else  
 {  
   echo'0';
 }    
 mysql_close($continued);
 ?>
```

Comment: sounds like cache issue... with the json call, try put "?date()" in the url and the cache might disappear. Check in js how to get the date of utc seconds since 1978 something...

Comment: the solve :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690194/how-to-clear-the-cache-for-json

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your PHP script is returning cached data. I always use the following header calls in my PHP script BEFORE returning any data to the client:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");   // Date in the past
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: @tayfnour It's a bit odd that you accept an answer which you say doesn't work - that's very confusing for future visitors.

Comment: That was my mistake , i'm sorry and i'm new in this website,